# Losing "some" decimal values after sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, decimal

This is a strange problem (to me anyways).

I'm doing a basic sorting assignment for class. Each sort is working except for the fact that after the sort it's dropping the values after the decimal for some values. The array is coming in from a separate file.

Pre-sort would be:
[1.25, 3.45, 6.3, 2.7]

After the sort:
[1, 2, 3.45, 6]

This is completely baffling to me since it's not affecting all of them.
So here is my good ole bubbleSort. (It was the shortest one I could post)

```
void bubbleSort(double bubAray[], int size){
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  int count=0;
  int temp;
  bool swap = true;

  cout <<"Pre Bubblesort" <<endl;
  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    cout <<bubAray[i] <<endl;;

  while (swap) {
    swap=false;
    j++;
    for(int i=0; i<size-j; i++){
        count++;
        if(bubAray[i]>bubAray[i+1]){
            temp=bubAray[i];
            bubAray[i]=bubAray[i+1];
            bubAray[i+1]=temp;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
}   
cout <<endl <<"Final Bubble Sort" <<endl <<endl;
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    cout <<bubAray[i] <<endl;
cout <<endl <<"Number of Bubble Sort Comparisons = " <<count <<endl;
}
```

Good news is that all my sorts work, I just have to figure out why these numbers aren't showing correctly.

Comment: Btw, stop listing all variables on top of the function. You might think it's clear code, but it's not.

Comment: So is it better to declare at time of use? I want to make it clear as possible. Thanks!

Comment: In C89, you had to declare variables at the top of each function. This policy was alleviated to decrease the amount of variables one has to keep in mind while reading code. Therefore, always introduce variables into scope at their very first usage in C and C++.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the definition of `temp` to

```
double temp;
```

When a value from the array is assigned to `temp`, it is truncated. Therefore, the decimal part is cut off.
The one `double` lucky enough to maintain its full value appears because it hasn't been assigned to `temp`; it was in the right order already.

---

Notes:

- Use the C++ standard library whenever possible; don't reinvent the wheel. Therefore, use `std::swap` instead<sup>1</sup>:

  ```
  std::swap(bubArray[i], bubArray[i + 1]);
  ```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to @PeteBecker!</sub>

Comment: Holy crap. Thanks! I can rest now. :)

Comment: Even better, use `std::swap` to exchange two values.

Comment: @PeteBecker Right, will add that.